# event to delete one line using backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a list of `<input type="text" class="lineString">` elements on my page all with the same class.  Each  has a button next to it, that when clicked, should remove that `<input type="text" class="lineString">` tag.

I tried this in my backbone event listener, but it removes all the  elements.

```
<input type="text" class="lineString" value="123" /> <input type="button" class="deleteLine" value="Delete" />

<br />

<input type="text" class="lineString" value="345" /> <input type="button" class="deleteLine" value="Delete" />


        deleteLine: function() {
            this.$('.lineString').remove();
        }
```

Is there a way to just get the  tag closest to the delete button?

THanks

Comment: could you add sample markup that includes both the input and the button so it's clear what the positional relationship is between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user jquery function "closest" (http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

$(this) -> assuming you are executing "deleteLine" function on button click, "this" scopes to clicked button.

```
deleteLine: function() {
       $(this).closest('.lineString').remove();
}
```

Comment: Actually this scopes to my view since I'm using backbone.js

Comment: then you can use event.target to get clicked element:

deleteLine: function(e) {
       $(e.target).closest('.lineString').remove();
}